# DRF always return not authenticated in Django rest framework fed on NextJS and Axios

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, next.js, axios

After testing on postman i get the right response but when i pushed the code for the frontend guys, I get a report that it's always returning false...

#### views.py

```
# Check authentication status
def check(request):
    data = {}
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        data['response'] = 'user is authenticated'
        data['name'] = request.user.name
        data['email'] = request.user.email
        data['phone_number'] = request.user.phone_number
        data['id_user'] = request.user.id_user
        data['passed_kyc'] = request.user.passed_kyc
    else:
        data['response'] = 'user is not authenticated'
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

It probably depends on what value they expect from the response, so ask them to show you the code or to tell you what key/value pair they expect from the response, and what values they expect to mean "true" or "false"

For example, if they expect a key "isAuthenticated" and a value of either "true/false", then you should be adding:

```
data['isAuthenticated'] = True/False #depending on whether user is authenticated or not
```